# RailsのアプリでMysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'takeshi'@'localhost' (using password: YES)、が発生してbundle exec rake db:createが実行できません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql

Rails アプリで GitHub から `git clone` をした後に、 `bundle exec rake db:create` を実行したら以下のエラーが発生しました。

> Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'takeshi'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

`config/database.yml` の内容:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  password: password
```

原因がわからずに困っております。
どうすれば、 `bundle exec rake db:create` を実行することができるでしょうか？
アドバイスの程、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `development:`の項目が`config/database.yml`内にあると思いますので、そちらを追記してもらえるでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、コメントありがとうございます！
こちらは何とか解決することができましたm(_ _)m

Comment: 自己解決されたときは解決方法を回答として投稿してもらえれば、同じ症状の人の助けになるのでよろしくおねがいします。